# Send object to JSP page

Tags: java, apache, jsp, tiles

I make insert in JSP (dogovorInfo.jsp) code (with Apache Tiles):

```
<t:insertAttribute name="${transportType}" />
```

In view.xml I define:

```
<tiles-definitions>
<definition name="dogovorInfo" template="/WEB-INF/views/dogovorInfo.jsp">
<put-attribute name="13" value="Auto" />
</definition>
<definition name="Auto" template="/WEB-INF/views/dogovorInfo/Auto.jsp" />
</tiles-definitions>
```

I have a ArrayList of objects in dogovorInfo.jsp, how send one object to Auto.jsp from dogovorInfo.jsp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way you could do is use some implicit objects (request, session) for storing the objects & then forward it to next jsp.